# Multiple exe and dll file in one MSI using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, merge, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm trying to merge multiple exe and dll files in one MSI file in order to install all of them using one installation file by using visual studio.

In addition to that I don't have the source code for the exe files. I used winx tools to have an exe file but I had the source code.

Comment: What problem are you having while trying to create the MSI? Can you share the configuration you are using for that MSI?

Comment: i'm not using any configuration for the moment because i don't have a clue on how to merge the files , i used microsoft visual studio installer extension succesfully with the source code but without the source code i don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you've been looking at Visual Studio setup examples that show build project output as an input to the setup project, and that's perhaps why you mention that you don't have access to the sources that would be used for the build.

The File View on Target System view in installer projects has destination folders (such as Application Folder). To add an exe or Dll just drag and drop the file into that folder, or right-click in the pane and do an Add File. Other files might go to Common Files, so again just add the files to that folder pane. Some of the time you may want to add the company name if it's not already part of the folder name.

This might help, it's old but installer projects are still like this:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/